# D3.js: Getting my own data for the layout

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have experimenting around with [the D3 cluster force layout](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7881887). 
However I am not sure as to how to bind the data and hence, I am not able to have my own data within.

This is what I have tried, without any binding, it's bound not to work.

```
d3.tsv("data.tsv", function(data){

    nodes = d3.range(n).map(function(data) {
        var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m),
            r = Math.sqrt((i + 1) / m * -Math.log(data.diskSpace)) * maxRadius,
            d = {
                cluster: i,
                radius: data.radius,
                x: Math.cos(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + width / 2 + Math.random(),
                y: Math.sin(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + height / 2 + Math.random()
            };
    if (!clusters[i] || (r > clusters[i].radius)) clusters[i] = d;
    return d;
});
```

This does not seem to work as expected.

What exactly is happening and how do I fix it?

**EDIT**: 
The TSV file

```
model diskSpace radius
DE431 8 8
DD342 16 18
...
```

Comment: The code example you added to you post generates random data and doesn't touch your data from 'data.tsv'. What exactly is in your tsv file?

Comment: I've added the format of the tsv file, pls have a look @Jieter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure the file is actually separated with tabs and not spaces. Loading a tsv in d3 looks like this:

```
d3.tsv('data.tsv', function (rows) {
    console.log(rows);
});
```

an array of rows will be logged to the console. Note that this call is made asynchronously, the `d3.tsv()`-function does not return the rows but instead calls a function with the rows as first argument.

Now we need to transform this data into something the d3 force layout understands:

```
d3.tsv('data.tsv', function (rows) {
    var nodes = rows.map(function (item) {
        var i = item['diskSpace'],
            r = +item['radius'], // note the + to convert to number here.
            d = {
              cluster: i,
              radius: r,
              x: Math.cos(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + width / 2 + Math.random(),
              y: Math.sin(i / m * 2 * Math.PI) * 200 + height / 2 + Math.random()
            };
        if (!clusters[i] || (r > clusters[i].radius)) {
            clusters[i] = d;
        }
        return d;
    });

    // insert code generating the force layout here (including the cluster and collide functions)
});
```

This will cluster the rows by diskSpace. Please note the comments I added.

Working [Demo here](http://bl.ocks.org/jieter/1a497e1fb7d817100f376f8b58f5d12f)

Comment: Thank you very much! 
There is a small change, what is the diskSpace is a string? Like "16GB", instead of 16?

Comment: diskSpace is not parsed to string (no + in front of it), it doesn't really matter if it's a string or a number, as long as it is the same for things you want to have in the same cluster.
I just tested it by appending the G, still works.